# On my JSP, how do I check if a field in my model contains errors?

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, model

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE (Java 6) on JBoss 7.1.3.  How do I check, on my JSP, if my model contains an error in a particular field?  I'm trying to elegantly display (in a specific order) the errors that result from a form submission.  So far I have

```
            <p class="error">
                <form:errors path="sampleUrl" cssClass="error" /><br/>
                <form:errors path="numValidDays" cssClass="error" /><br/>
                <form:errors path="role" cssClass="error" /><br/>
                <form:errors path="sampleWord" cssClass="error" /><br/>
                <form:errors path="maxUses" cssClass="error" /><br/>
            </p>
```

THe problem is if there isn't an error in the field, there are all these extra "<br/>" tags, which makes my page look ugly.  Any help here is appreciated.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<p class="error">
    <form:errors path="sampleUrl" cssClass="error" element="div" /><br/>
    <form:errors path="numValidDays" cssClass="error" element="div" /><br/>
    <form:errors path="role" cssClass="error" element="div" /><br/>
    <form:errors path="sampleWord" cssClass="error" element="div" /><br/>
    <form:errors path="maxUses" cssClass="error" element="div" /><br/>
</p>
```

so instead of a `span`, the error message will be embedded in a `div` no more `<br/>` needed

from the spring-form.tld

> element Specifies the HTML element that is used to render the
>   enclosing errors.